# Does iWork support OpenOffice filetypes?

Tags: iwork, uti

I was thinking about getting iWork as a replacement for OpenOffice. 
Since I usually saved my files to the OpenOffice format (OpenDocument), I was wondering if it's possible to read these files with iWork. Most important would be reading of `.odt` (Text) and `.ods` (Spreadsheets). The ability to write these files isn't *that* important.

Saving the files to MS-Office first isn't an option though.

I also noticed that Quick-Look displays `.odt` files on a system that doesn't have OpenOffice installed so there's probably already some OpenDocument support built into OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just created some test documents (`.odt`, `.ods`, `.odf`) in OpenOffice and I was unable to open them in iWork. I was able, however, to open the `.odt` in TextEdit, which probably accounts for the Quick Look compatibility you mentioned.