# Convert from OpenOffice to Pages

Tags: pages

Does anybody has experience in how to best convert OpenOffice.org documents to pages documents.

[Obviously, it can be read in a Text Editor.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3985/does-iwork-support-openoffice-filetypes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I do it is I export the OpenOffice document to Microsoft Word DOC format, then use Pages to convert that into a Pages document. There may be some formatting loss, but I'm not aware of a way to convert directly from one format to the other.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest saving in RTF format instead of Word format as OS X has a very competent RFT engine as used by TextEdit and, I would guess, Pages. This avoids the conversion in and out of a poorly defined format with no public specification.

Comment: I've typically found that RTF has even less support for page layout than DOC.

Comment: Where is the public specification for rtf. I used RTF between NeXT (OSX predecessor) and word and they were not the same.

Comment: @Mark http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140277(v=office.10).aspx

Comment: That is MS's spec - but do all other readers use that - they did used not to

Comment: @Mark According to Wikipedia it is a Microsoft format, thus *the* spec., and designed specifically for document interchange. If other vendors are not implementing it correctly (with the understanding that earlier versions were not necessarily as rigorously defined, something rectified in later versions) that is not a Microsoft failing. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format